# How do I get the thread index after calling newthread?

Tags: java, c, lua, java-native-interface, jnlua

In JNLUA, newThread() is a void function in Java but I don't quite understand the C code behind implementing the java side of the function. Also, would someone explain why the original author would return the index/pointer?

Comment: `Thread#newThread(Runnable)` returns a `Thread`, not `void`.  Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

`newThread` pushes the new thread onto the Lua stack. There is no need to return a value. Interfacing via a pointer value would be challenging to make safe (and poor style anyway I guess), and the index is readily available without returning it (e.g. via `getTop` or simply by keeping track of the stack size or by using negative indices). This is more or less the same for all parts of the API that push a value onto the stack.

Note that JNLUA's `newThread` differs a bit from Lua's `lua_newthread`; threads in JNLUA are a little less general and more intended to be used like Lua coroutines (which are, of course, also Lua threads) -- `newThread` takes the value from the top of the stack and uses it as the "start function" for the coroutine (which will be invoked when calling `resume` for the thread the first time).

I won't speculate on the author's decision to expose threads in this way; returning a `LuaState` (and/or exposing `lua_tothread`) could also be a reasonable way to implement things a bit closer to the original Lua API.

This is the guts of the implementation:

```
static int newthread_protected (lua_State *L) {
    lua_State *T;
    
    T = lua_newthread(L);
    lua_insert(L, 1);
    lua_xmove(L, T, 1);
    return 1;
}
```

This is done in a protected call because `lua_newthread` can throw an exception (if it runs out of memory). The only argument (and thus the only thing initially on the stack) is the start function at index 1. `lua_newthread` will push the new thread object to the stack at index 2. Then `lua_insert` will reverse the order of the new thread object and the start function and `lua_xmove` transfers the start function to the new thread and then the new thread is returned (which leaves it on top of the caller's stack).

In Lua, a new thread with the start function already on the stack can sort of be treated equivalently to a yielded thread by `lua_resume`, so this is basically what JNLUA does -- its `resume` can be used to start the thread with the previously provided function.